# Can application/config/email.php be modified with php code in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, model-view-controller, config

I have a settings_view in which there is a textField and I would like to give the user the option to modify `application/config/email.php` and more precisely the `$config['smtp_user']` so the latter would receive the string entered by the user.
I already know how to get the controller to receive the value by creating a form in the view and then send it to another view or use the value in a db query but I'm wondering whether I can actually make it so the `config/email.php` can be modified.
I would appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction or tell me to stop searching if this is not doable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can place your settings inside config/email.php, but you can also modify them inside your controller. It overwrites variables that you are only interested and will also use the rest from config file.

```
$new_config_values = array(
   'new_key' => 'new value'
);

$this->email->initialize($new_config_values);
```

Comment: This is the correct way. Don't make your code to manipulate the file itself.